# Getting Null in TreeMap using Comparator

Tags: java, treemap

I have a class named `Empl` and two Comparators named as `MySalaryComp` and `MyNameComp`.

When I run this code I am getting `null` as a value in `MySalaryComp` as shown in output below.

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        TreeMap<Empl, String> tm = new TreeMap<Empl, String>(new MyNameComp());
        tm.put(new Empl("zzz", 3000), "RAM");
        tm.put(new Empl("aaa", 6000), "JOHN");
        Set<Empl> keys = tm.keySet();
        for (Empl key : keys) {
            System.out.println(key + " ==> " + tm.get(key));
        }

        TreeMap<Empl, String> trmap = new TreeMap<Empl, String>(new MySalaryComp());
        trmap.put(new Empl("zzz", 3000), "RAM");
        trmap.put(new Empl("aaa", 6000), "JOHN");
        Set<Empl> ks = trmap.keySet();
        for (Empl key : ks) {
            System.out.println(key + " ==> " + trmap.get(key));
        }
    }
}

class MyNameComp implements Comparator<Empl> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
}

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if (e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class Empl {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s) {
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }


}
```

The output of above code is :

```
Name: aaa-- Salary: 6000 ==> JOHN
Name: zzz-- Salary: 3000 ==> RAM
Name: zzz-- Salary: 3000 ==> null
Name: aaa-- Salary: 6000 ==> null
```

Can some one help me understand why null values are showing ? And how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator is not implemented correctly.
Read up on the JavaDocs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

Try this:

```
@Override
public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
  return e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary();
}
```

**Why do you need to return 0?**

 If you look at the source code of TreeMap you will see this:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
  // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
  if (comparator != null)
    return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
  if (key == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
  Entry<K,V> p = root;
  while (p != null) {
    int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
    if (cmp < 0)
      p = p.left;
    else if (cmp > 0)
      p = p.right;
    else
      return p; // <--Here
  }
  return null;
}
```

If the comparator is never 0 he will dereference the child branch which will be null.

Sidenote:
You can also make your comparator functional, like so:

```
Comparator<Employee> salaryComparator = (e1, e2) -> (e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary());
TreeMap<Employee, String> trmap = new TreeMap<>(salaryComparator);
```

Comment: Why returning 0 is reflecting in get() method of treemap, Please explain

Comment: But I am able to put the elements in KT right ? Problem is when I a fetching the elements from KT. Please go through the above answer

Comment: You will have to walk the sourcecode yourself. Check out the put and get methods.

Comment: Hehe, found it. Fun practice.

Answer (score 1):

Because my salary comparator never return 0 when two objects have same salary.

You need to fix MySalaryComp to return zero when salaries of both objects are same.

Comment: Yes working great, Can you please explain why returning 0 will change the map output

Comment: Simply because  treemap relies on given comparator while  searching the given key. If comparator is not able to determines two objects are same, so map will consider given key was never stored

Answer (score 0):

Override the comparator correctly: You can use the in built integer comparator

`return Integer.valueOf(e1.getSalary()).compareTo(e2.getSalary());`